# Python socket, How to receive the response after sending a request

Tags: python, sockets

I have a socket server (in MQL4) that is running and capable of sending and receiving data based on a requests sent by a client.  I have a example of a client below with a class that instantiates the socket client and makes a request for the server time.

The output of the code below is:

```bash
Connected to socket server > 127.0.0.1:7001
2023.08.25 23:59:58>server_datetime>0>2023.08.25 23:59:58>!
```

my expected output is:

```bash
Connected to socket server > 127.0.0.1:7001
2023.08.25 23:59:58>server_datetime>0>2023.08.25 23:59:58>!
:: 2023.08.25 23:59:58>server_datetime>0>2023.08.25 23:59:58>!
```

...as the `print('::', resp)` in `get_server_time` should produce the 3rd line of output.

**My question is how to get the received socket response back to the calling function of my `Trader` class?**  The line `resp = self.MT4.RECV()` does not seem to execute, since the print statement does not run.  My server also sends out a notification when a new bar opens and I want to ensure that the response that is sent back is the response to `get_server_time` call and not the new bar notification.

Client socket:

```py
import threading
import socket


class MT4SocketClient:
    server = None
    port = None
    client_socket = None
    connection_close_by = None
    response = None
    connected = False
    threads: list[threading] = []
    response_dict = {}
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.threads.append(threading.Thread(target=self.RECV, daemon=True))

    def verify_connection(self) -> bool:
        try:
            # this will try to read bytes without blocking and also without removing them from buffer (peek only)
            data = self.client_socket.recv(10000)
            if len(data) == 0:
                return False
        except BlockingIOError:
            return True  # socket is open and reading from it would block
        except ConnectionResetError:
            return False  # socket was closed for some other reason
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print("unexpected exception when checking if a socket is open")
            return True
        return True

    def connect(self, server="127.0.0.1", port=None):
        self.server = server
        if isinstance(port, int):
            self.port = port
        else:
            raise ConnectionAbortedError('Invalid port')
        try:
            self.client_socket.connect((server, port))  # connect to the server
            if self.verify_connection():
                self.connected = True
                print(f'Connected to socket server > {self.server}:{port}')
        except socket.error as err:
            print(err)
            print(f'Error connecting with socket server. Host {self.server} Port {port}')
            self.connected = False

    def start(self):
        for thread in self.threads:
            thread.start()

    def RECV(self):
        while True:
            response = self.client_socket.recv(10000).decode('utf-8')
            if response.endswith('>!'):
                print(response)
                return response

    def SEND(self, command: str):

        command = command + '|!'
        try:
            self.client_socket.send(bytes(command, "utf-8"))
        except socket.error as msg:
            self.connected = False
            print('Unexpected socket communication error')
            print(msg)
            return None


class Trader:

    def __init__(self):
        self.MT4 = MT4SocketClient()
        self.MT4.connect(port=7001)
        self.MT4.start()

    def get_server_time(self):
        self.MT4.SEND('server_datetime')
        resp = self.MT4.RECV()
        print('::', resp)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    trader = Trader()
    trader.get_server_time()

    while trader.MT4.connected:
        pass
```

Comment: After connecting to the server, you are reading from the server to "verify" the connection, before you then start the thread to read more. That initial read is going to discard the server's 1st response. Why are you "verifying" the connection at all? After you are connected, just move on. Unless the server sends a greeting, there is nothing to verify